# How to allow html form to submit only if numbers in field adds up to a certain sum

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that inserts data into a database.

There are many input fields in this form, 4 of these fields are meant to input numbers:

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="Text1"> <input type="number" name="Number1">
<input type="text" name="Text2"> <input type="number" name="Number2">
<input type="text" name="Text3"> <input type="number" name="Number3">
<input type="text" name="Text4"> <input type="number" name="Number4">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

My question: How to allow the form to submit ONLY IF the inputs in those 4 fields adds up to 100? And display some sort of error to tell the user if the total is not yet 100.

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need some JavaScript. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have no idea where to start. I'm new sorry.

Comment: You have to use javascript to do that. Get the value of each "number", make the sum and check if it is > 100. With a bit of digging you can do this very easily juste by copy/pasting some code on the web.

Comment: yeah, the problem as nothing to do with Php, that is executing server-side, so only when you submit and reload a page

Comment: Here is a good place to start - http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript

Comment: Please could anyone provide the JavaScript to get it working? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `onSubmit` handler to your form:

```
<form action="page.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

Then create `validate()` function to check your condition. Something like this might work:

```
<script>
function validate() {
    var n1 = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('Number1')[0].value);
    var n2 = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('Number2')[0].value);
    var n3 = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('Number3')[0].value);
    var n4 = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('Number4')[0].value);
    if (n1+n2+n3+n4 == 100) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Sum is not 100");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Note that in case of error the function returns `false` - that prevents form submission.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just tried this and the "Sum is not 100 message" keeps popping up even tho the sum is 100.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to cast values to integers. I've edited my response - please try now.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that in "page.php":

```
//check
//form.html is the form you posted
//Do this for all the fields
if ($_POST["Number1"]+$_POST["Number2"]+$_POST["Number3"]+$_POST["Number4"] < 100) header("location:form.html&error= Error message");
```

Then Add some php code before form.html:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['error']) echo $_GET['error'];
?>

<form action="page.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="Text1"> <input type="number" name="Number1">
<input type="text" name="Text2"> <input type="number" name="Number2">
<input type="text" name="Text3"> <input type="number" name="Number3">
<input type="text" name="Text4"> <input type="number" name="Number4">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

You can do that in JS also and it's better. i'll try to show you but i believe you'll find many useful stuff if you searched.

Comment: Thanks. I need all the number1 + number2 + number3 + number4 = 100 in order for the form to be able to submit. Does this only check individual numbers if they are <100 ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want their sum to equal 4:

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="Text1"> <input type="number" name="Number1">
<input type="text" name="Text2"> <input type="number" name="Number2">
<input type="text" name="Text3"> <input type="number" name="Number3">
<input type="text" name="Text4"> <input type="number" name="Number4">
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="checkinput()">
</form>

<sript>
function checkinput() {
  var n1=document.getElementsByName("Number1");
  var n2=document.getElementsByName("Number2");
  var n3=document.getElementsByName("Number3");
  var n4=document.getElementsByName("Number4");

  if (n1[0].value + n2[0].value + n3[0].value + n4[0].value != 4) {
      return false;
  } 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To check out a live example click this link [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ngyAk)

basically if this is your form

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  Some Text:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Number1:<input type="number"><br>
  Number2:<input type="number"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and this your javascript

```
function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
total_sum = 100
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    if(inputs[i].type == 'number'){
      total_sum = total_sum -  inputs[i].value;
    }
  }
if(total_sum != 0){
  alert("did not add up to 100")
  return false;
} 
else alert('total was 100')
}
```

Pressing submit will check the form and alert the result

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
 var numbers = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=number]');
 var inputs = [].slice.call(numbers);
 var total = 0;

inputs.forEach(function(input){
    var value = (input.value !== '') ? input.value : 0;
    total += parseInt(value);
 });

if(total >= 100){
// continue your form processing here

}else{
  alert('total number should be 100');
   e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

[demo] http://jsbin.com/fozalo/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You can actually also do it with php.

page.php:

```
    <?php

    if ($POST_["Number1"] + $POST_["Number2"] + $POST_["Number3"] + $POST_["Number4"] > 100)  {


     //Do whatever you want if numbers add up to 100

        }
    else {

    echo "some kind of error message here";

    }
    ?>
```